# Dot notation in psql query - what is the difference?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In some Rails code I found these lines:

```rb
User.where('created_at >= ?', '2018-10-10').count
# which results in:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE (created_at >= '2018-10-10')
=> 1234
```

```rb
User.where('users.created_at >= ?', '2018-10-10').count
# which results in:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE (users.created_at >= '2018-10-10')
=> 1234
```

Is there any difference between using `WHERE users.created_at` and `WHERE created_at` ?

Comment: In this context there is no difference but what you are referring to is a called a qualified column name (or multi part identifier) and if you had 2 tables joined together which both had a created_at column you would need to specified which `created_at` column to use in the where clause otherwise there would be ambiguity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference in this case.

The dotted notation you're seeing is called *qualified column names*.

There's no advantage to using qualified column names in your example query, since you have only one table. It's clear which table the `created_at` column belongs to.

But if you had a more complex query with JOIN and so on, it would be a good idea to qualify each column with the table they belong to, in case more than one table has a column of the same name.